# Access the identical view controller using instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard

I had a `UIViewController` in storyboard with a storyboard id called "MyViewController" (embedded in a `UINavigationController`as entry point),
and I was trying to access it from another class using `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` like:

**MyAccessor.swift**

```
func accessMyViewController(){
  let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
  let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyViewController")
  print(vc.description)
}
```

**MyViewController.swift**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  print(self.description)
}
```

**Console**

```
<MyViewController: 0x7ff6ab76f9c0>
<MyViewController: 0x7ff6ab557410>
```

I got different memory addresses printed out,

weren't they supposed to be the same one?

Comment: You are only instantiating the vc, not displaying it

Comment: @MidhunMP it gets displayed since it's embedded in a navigation controller which is set to be the initial view controller.

Comment: When you use instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier it allocates new instance. So there is two instance in this case, one displayed (initial view controller), second one you allocated using code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIStoryboard/instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:) of this method, it will always create a new instance:

> This method creates a new instance of the specified view controller each time you call it.

If you need the same instance of the view controller, you need to store the reference somewhere else (e.g. the view controller which creates the first instance).

It might be possible that the first instance `MyViewController` is created by the storyboard itself for it being the initial view controller.

**Update:**

After looking at the code and question again, I now know what exactly happens.
As stated the navigation controller is the entry point of the storyboard. This means that the first instance of `MyViewController` is created by the storyboard which leads to the first print inside the `viewDidLoad` method.
The second instance is created by the code in *MyAccessor.swift*. The print inside the same file leads to the second output line. However, the view of the second instance is never loaded, which causes `viewDidLoad` to be never called. If you'd call `loadViewIfNeeded` on `vc` it would lead to a third output line, which would print the same memory address as the `print` inside *MyAccessor.swift*.

Comment: As far as I can understand from questions, author instantiated *one* view controller.

Comment: The console part in the original question lists two instances of MyViewController. But the `print` statements actually would print the navigationController (from within MyAccessor.swift) and the view controller (from within MyViewController.swift).

Comment: Yes, that's why question was asked: he instantiated 1 VC, but it prints different addresses.

Comment: Again, that's not possible with the code shown. The view controller is definitively instantiated twice. Maybe the first time is because it's the entry point for the storyboard. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: Yes, I just read the question again, and you were right. Author just instantiates 2 different view controllers.

Comment: It is the initial view controller in storyboard. Is there a way to access the same one?

Comment: You could use the `rootViewController` property on the `AppDelegate`'s `window` which should be the NavigationController. Or you could make your `MyViewController` register itself in e.g. the `AppDelegate`. But usually you shouldn't need to directly access ViewControllers, better would be to communicate with your VC using some kind of model structure.

Answer (score 2):

Probably your navigationController is the **storyboard entry point**.

So, if it's true, there are two instances..one created during your application start, the other called programmatically from you code.

P.S.: **viewDidLoad** will not be called just by instantiating a view controller, see [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLoad) for details.., otherwise you have seen three prints..

[image]

If you want to see immediatly your situation try to modify your print lines:

**MyAccessor.swift**

```
func accessMyViewController(){
    ...
    print("∙ \(NSStringFromClass(self.dynamicType)) - vc details : \(vc.description) ")
}
```

**MyViewController.swift**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    print("∙ \(NSStringFromClass(self.dynamicType)) - self details : \(self.description) ")
}
```

Comment: You mean an initial view controller gets initiated automatically before I can do anything?